# Prove the laws of exponents by induction

Tags: real-analysis, induction

We inductively define $a^1=a, a^{n+1}=a^n a$. I want to show that $a^{n+m}=a^n a^m$.

By definition, this is true if $m=1$. Now for $m=2$, we have 
$$
\begin{align}
a^{n+2} =& a^{(n+1)+1}\\
=& a^{n+1}a \\
=& \left(a^{n}a\right)a \\
=& a^{n}\left(aa\right) \\
=& a^{n}a^2 
\end{align}
$$
How do I finish this proof?

Comment: "For $m=2$", why are you proving $a^{n+2} = a^{n+2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, the sentences

"By definition, this is true if $m=1$" is a correct step

"Now for $m=2$, we have ..." not correct! in proof by induction you never go
through next values 1, 2, 3 literally, this would never end
but you check the proposition in this case replacing m by m+1 !

Here is how it works

I want to show that (proposition or statement)

$a^{n+m}=a^n a^m$

is true for all $m$

Ok, then first I do assume that this is true as it is

*- Oh, you haven't proven anything!*

Not, yet, I've just started. Now let us replace m by m+1 in the proposition

$a^{n+m+1}=a^n a^{m+1}$.

arranging the first exponential sum

$a^{(n+m)+1}=a^n a^{m+1}$.

we apply now the given definition (something powered by something +1 ...) in both sides

$a^{(n+m)}a=a^n a^{m}a$.

now remove common factor $a$ in both sides

$a^{(n+m)}=a^n a^{m}$.

Which is the original proposition which we assumed to be true at the beginning

*- Yes, it is assumed but we don't know ...*

Ok, what we have done so far is proving that if it is true for $m$ then it is true for $m+1$, right ?

Let us check with $m=1$, if this is true (the very only replacement by a real number in our proof) then it has also to be true for 2, also for 3, 4, 5 ... and so on, that is for any $m$

Answer (score 4):

Fix any $a\in\mathbb R$ and any $m\in\mathbb N$ and let $P(n)$ be the statement $a^ma^n=a^{m+n}$ and show that for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $P(n)$ is true.

For $n=1$, $P(n)$ is true since by definition, $a^ma^1=a^ma=a^{m+1}$.

Now suppose that for some $n=k$, $P(n)$ is true, i.e., $a^ma^k=a^{m+k}$. Then $a^ma^{k+1}=a^m(a^ka)=(a^ma^k)a=a^{m+k}a=a^{(m+k)+1}=a^{m+(k+1)}$.

Thus, $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$, and since $P(1)$ is true, $P(n)$ is true for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

Then assume $a^na^m = a^{n+m}$ and prove $a^na^{m+1} = a^{n+m+1}$. I would say this is very similar to your $m=2$ proof above.

Answer (score 1):

assume $m=k\Rightarrow a^{n+k}=a^na^k$
then we should prove that $m=k+1\Rightarrow a^{n+(k+1)}=a^na^{k+1}$
$$a^{n+(k+1)}=a^{(n+k)+1}=a^{n+k}a\qquad\qquad because\;a^{n+1}=a^na$$
$$\Rightarrow a^{n+(k+1)}=a^{n+k}a=a^na^ka=a^na^{k+1}\qquad\qquad because\;a^{n+1}=a^na$$

Answer (score 0):

Step one: show that $a^n\cdot a=a^{n+1}$ (given).

Step two: assume that $a^n\cdot a^k=a^{n+k}$.

Then $a^n\cdot a^{k+1}=a^n\cdot a^k\cdot a=a^{n+k}\cdot a=a^{n+k+1}$

then add a bunch of useless words and you're done!