# Proving $a^ma^n=a^{m+n}$ by induction when $n$ or $m$ is negative (or both)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, induction

Suppose we have already proved this exponent law for when $m,n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1355502/prove-the-laws-of-exponents-by-induction). Also suppose $x^{-n}=\frac{1}{x^n}$ is given as a definition.

Let $m=-\lambda$ and $n=-\gamma$, where $\lambda,\gamma\in\mathbb{Z^+}$. Then 
\begin{align}
a^ma^n&=\frac{1}{a^\lambda}\cdot\frac{1}{a^\gamma}\tag{by definition}\\[0.5em]
&= \frac{1}{a^\lambda a^\gamma}\tag{simplify}\\[0.5em]
&= \frac{1}{a^{\lambda+\gamma}}\tag{by previous result}\\[0.5em]
&= a^{-(\lambda+\gamma)}\tag{by definition}\\[0.5em]
&= a^{-\lambda-\gamma}\tag{simplify}\\[0.5em]
&= a^{m+n}.\tag{by definition}
\end{align}

Does that look like a legitimate argument? Furthermore, what would the argument be if, WLOG, $m>0$ and $n<0$? If we let $n=-\gamma$, where $\gamma\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ and $\frac{a^m}{a^n}=a^{m-n}$ were already established for $m,n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, then would
\begin{align}
a^ma^n&=a^ma^{-\gamma}\tag{by definition}\\[0.5em]
&= \frac{a^m}{a^\gamma}\tag{by definition}\\[0.5em]
&= a^{m-\gamma}\tag{by previous result}\\[0.5em]
&= a^{m+n}\tag{by definition}
\end{align}
be a legitimate argument as well? Is there an easier way to rigorously prove exponent laws? Most of what I have seen has only related to proving these laws for when the powers are positive integers. What about when they are simply real numbers?

Comment: You forgot to say what type of number $\,a\,$ is.

Comment: @BillDubuque My mistake: $a\in\mathbb{R}$ for everything.